# swiftとC言語の関連性について

Tags: swift, xcode, c

現在swiftでアプリ開発をおこなっております。
そこでswiftと他の言語との関連性について質問があるのでよろしくお願いいたします。

アプリ開発で、主成分分析を使用したいのですが、MATLABやC言語に書いてあるコードを見てみると、数百行のコードが存在します。
そこでC言語のコードをそのままswift言語で使用する方法は何かありますでしょうか？

例えばMATLABですとC言語を使用したい場合、MEX関数を用いることで、実装が可能となります。
このようにswiftとC言語に関連性があるかどうか、さらにはその方法を教えていただきたいです。

もし知っている方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授お願いします。

Answer (score 1):

Objective-CはC言語のスーパーセットなので、Objective-Cがリンクできれば、Cもリンクできることになります。細かなことは[ここ](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)に書かれています。

最初のステップとしては、Swiftのプロジェクトの中に適当なObjective-Cのファイルを作ります。ファイルの中身はなんでもいいです。ともかくXcodeに「Objective-Cのファイルがある」と認識させると、「ブリッジヘッダーを設定するか？」というダイアログが出てきます。

Yesと答えると`<プロジェクト名>-Bridging-Header.h`というファイルができますので、そのファイルに`#import <C言語のヘッダーファイル.h>`と追加します。

リンカーの設定や、その他の制約などありますが、まずはここまで試してみてください。